# AWS S3 cli not working on Windows server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This works on my Linux box, but I can't get a simple AWS S3 cli command to work on a Windows server (2012).

I'm running a simple copy command to a bucket.  I get the following error:

```
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid length for parameter Key, value: 0, valid range: 1-inf
```

I googled this, couldn't find anything relevant.  And I'm not the best at working with Windows servers.

What does this error actually mean?

Here's the command:

```
aws s3 cp test.zip s3://my-bucket
```

Version:

```
aws-cli/1.11.158 Python/2.7.9 Windows/2012Server botocore/1.7.16
```

Comment: Show the command? Also,make sure you are running an up-to-date version of the CLI tool.

Comment: @MarkB Added command and version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message:

> Invalid length for parameter Key

Is telling you that you need to specify a Key for your object (a filename basically). Like so:

```
aws s3 cp test.zip s3://my-bucket/test.zip
```

Answer (score 18):

You might try this:

```
aws s3 cp test.zip s3://my-bucket --recursive
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message has nothing to do with specifying the file name on the destination file path (that will be taken from the origin).  It has everything to do with having a valid access key and secret key setup.

Run the following command to verify if you have configured your credentials.

```
aws configure list
```